# Magento: No 'Add product' button on back end new order

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I've just installed the latest version of Magento 1.8 and everything is great and works perfectly. However, we've just discovered that there is no 'Add product' button on the admin new orders page. Everything else works as before, including:

- customers can order from the front end
- admin can add a product from the 'last ordered' or 'recently viewed products' from the customer recent activity panel

It therefore seems to be an issue with just this button alone. We've tried the below fixes without any success:

- removed theme from our site (revert to default); button still missing
- noted a previous bug relating to payment methods in v 1.7; tried copying all payment .phtml files to theme; button still missing

At a loss as to what this could be. All other functions appear to be working. Has anyone got any pointers as to how to resolve this?

Comment: An update: we've just tried using a different browser and have had (some) success. The browser used above was Chrome. We've tried it in IE and the Add products button is there, although some of the other buttons appear incorrectly. We don't really want to switch to IE as there seem to be several bugs with IE and Magento and Chrome has always seemed the most stable. However, does this info help anyone point us to where the issue may be?

Comment: anything on the javascript console? and in the logs?

Comment: @Ben: have you been able to solve this problem? I'm having this issue too in `magento 1.8`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly an ideal fix, because it involves changing core functionality, but the "Add Product" backend button is handled in:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Create/Items.php
```

What you're looking for specifically is the **getButtonsHtml** function.  Having the same issue after upgrading from 1.6 to 1.9, I changed mine to look like this:

```
public function getButtonsHtml()
{
    $html = '';
    // Make buttons to be rendered in opposite order of addition. This makes "Add products" the last one.
    $this->_buttons = array_reverse($this->_buttons);

    //If the buttons array isn't empty, let it do its thing
    if (!empty($this->_buttons))
    {
        foreach ($this->_buttons as $buttonData) {
            $html .= $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')->setData($buttonData)->toHtml();
        }
    }
    else {
        $addButtonData = array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Add Products'),
            'onclick' => "order.productGridShow(this)",
            'class' => 'add',
        );

        $html .= $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')->setData($addButtonData)->toHtml();
    }
    return $html;
}
```

It works, but it's really just a hackjob fix.  I'm hoping someone more knowledgeable than I can come up with a proper solution.

Edit - Leaving the above answer, but I sussed out my personal problem.  I was running a dual install of Magento, and I forgot to change the .htaccess of my Minify library to re-route to the newer install.  So it was compiling the old 1.6 JavaScript and using it on my 1.9 install.